# How to Use Bean shell preprocessor to Generate Dynamic HTTP Request In JMeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, dynamic-data, performance-testing, beanshell

In my Application the number of Http Request parameters are varied depends up on the Previous Http Response.

### Scenario:

If we select one option in drop down and click on submit. After Submit Transaction, It will display a table of data.

Each row in table has text boxes, we have to fill the data in these text boxes and click on Update Button. We can send data easily with the CSVDataSetConfig, But the size of table will be varied for different selection in drop down.

The Size of table can be obtain using Regular Expression Extractor.

Depending up on the table size and table rows we have to create the Http Request.

My Requirement is to Create Http Request which can handle Dynamic Http Request Parameters.

Answer (score 0):

If the table size depends on the option in drop down, you could just specify all steps one by one.
If the table size doesn't depends, you can use [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and [IF Controller](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) to verify some text boxes name or something like this is present on the page. I'm not sure, it's only my assumption

Comment: Can we use Bean shell Pre Processor to generate dynamic HTTP Request using dummy HTTP Request Sampler?

Answer (score 0):

Use JSR223 Post processor in the request where the table with varied size generates. From the response of that request extract the table size by regular expression or if it is a JSON response use below,

```
var json = JSON.parse(prev.getResponseDataAsString());  
vars.put("tableSize",json.tablesize);
```

1. **prev** contains the sampler response under which you have the JSR223 element.
2. **vars** is jmeter Map for variables. Add table's size as a variable to it

now use the ${tableSize} wherever you want.